# Python ElementTree "Invalid descendant" error

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file, `foo.xml`:

```
<foo>
    <bar>
        <baz phrase="hello"/>
    </bar>
    <quux phrase="goodbye"/>
</foo>
```

I'm parsing it with this Python code:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
# or if you don't have lxml: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc = ET.parse('foo.xml').getroot()

for elem in doc.findall('*[@phrase]'):
    print(elem)
```

That gives me:

```
<Element 'quux' at 0x7fa1419a1d18>
```

Now I want to find all elements with a `phrase` attribute, so I tried `'.//[@phrase]'` but then `findall()` fails:

```
SyntaxError: invalid descendant
```

I don't understand what's wrong.  The same error message appears if I use the built-in `xml.etree.ElementTree` instead of `lxml`.

Note that `'.//'` works, but returns `bar, baz, quux` and I don't want `bar` because it doesn't have a `phrase` attribute.

Comment: you need `*` in `.//*[@phrase]`

Comment: @furas that should be an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need `*`  as tag name in `".//*[@phrase]"`